# Get text next to the selected element using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have following HTML:

```
<div id="foo"><span id="bar">BAR</span> hello</div>
```

I've created `BeautifulSoup` object:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div id="foo"><span id="bar">BAR</span> hello</div>')
bar = soup.find(id="bar")
```

How can I get `hello` text using `bar` element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> data = '<div id="foo"><span id="bar">BAR</span> hello</div>'
>>> soup = bs(data)
>>> bar = soup.find(id="bar")
>>> bar
<span id="bar">BAR</span>
>>> bar.next_sibling.strip()
u'hello'
```